# IF clause is not validating NSString function return?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have the function below that validates the return of another function (function searchPlaces that returns NSString). When I run it, it seems that the if clause is not being called, because the NSLog(@"Function Return: %@",nova url); appears in Console.

Can someone tell me if there's any mistake in the code? (For sure there is a mistake!)

```
- (void) buttonPushRandomViewController1 {

    UIViewController *randomViewController = [self randomViewController3];

    NSString *novaurl = [self searchPlaces];
    NSLog(@"Function Return: %@",novaurl);

    if (novaurl == @"OK") {
        randomViewController.title = @"Resultado";
        [self.master pushViewController:randomViewController animated:YES];

        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:novaurl]];
        [webView loadRequest:request];
    }else if (novaurl == @"ZERO_RESULTS") {
        UIAlertView *zeroResults = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Ops!" message: @"Sorry, nothing found!" 
                                                             delegate: self cancelButtonTitle: @"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [zeroResults show];
        [zeroResults release];
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should not comparing `NSString`s with the `==` operator.  The `==` operator performs *reference equality* on Objective-C object types: it only returns true if both operands refer to the exact same object.  Even if two strings are copies of each other, `==` will return false if they refer to different instances.

You want to use *value equality* instead.  You can compare strings using the [`-isEqualToString:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) method:

```
if ([novaurl isEqualToString:@"OK"]) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: @CainaSouza: You have not accepted an answer to any of your questions.  If you found that this solved your problem, you should [accept it as the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 5):

You should use `isEqualToString:` method of NSString to check for equality of strings. == operator does a pointer comparison and sometimes it will return NO although the contents of the strings are the same.