# NSString comparison not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, rss, nsstring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IF clause is not validating NSString function return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787020/if-clause-is-not-validating-nsstring-function-return)

what I am trying to do is get items from an RSS feed and store them in arrays depending on their type.  But the problem is when I compare the strings to separate the items nothing happens I have checked and the strings are exactly the same but it says they are not equal.

```
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

    if (eventsList != nil) {
        for (int i = 0; i<[eventsList count]; i++) {
            NSMutableString* str = [[eventsList objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"category"];
            if ([str isEqualToString:@"normal"]) {
                normalEvents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                [normalEvents addObject:eventsList];
            } else if ([str isEqualToString:@"sub"]) {

                subEvents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                [subEvents addObject:eventsList];
            } else if ([str isEqualToString:@"main"]) {
                NSLog(@"salve mundi");

                mainEvents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                [mainEvents addObject:eventsList];
            } else {
                NSLog(@"%@",str);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You keep saying "it didn't work" in your comments. What didn't work? What results are you seeing?

Comment: log your `str` before `if` statement.

Answer (score 4):

Using `==` you compare the objects' address. To compare the contents of two NSStrings you have to use the instance method `[str isEqualToString:@"sub"]` instead.

Comment: That is what I tried first but it does not work.

Comment: It has to. If that returns `NO`, then your strings are different or `str` is `nil`. Try logging `str`. `NSLog("String 1: %@\nString 2: %@", str, @"sub");`.

Comment: it still is not working for me.

Comment: what didn't work. have you tried log your `str`?

Comment: yes I have and it is exactly the same as the string it is being compared to.

Comment: Post the exact code and the logs.

Answer (score 2):

I would do some tests to ensure that the string is equal. For example, if it has whitespaces at the end or beginning, if it's uppercase, etc..

```
[[yourString lowercaseString] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if([str isEqualToString:@"normal"])
```